# “The easiest way …”

Tags: english-to-german, meaning

Translating “the easiest way to carry bricks …” to *Der einfachste Weg, Ziegel zu tragen*, doesn’t seem right. *Der einfachste Weg* seems like only for “The easiest route”. Should “the easiest way to carry bricks” be *Die einfachste Methode …* or *Die einfachste Art*? Or can *Weg* be used in this more figurative, general way?

Comment: Oh yeah, hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] for any questions on how it works =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it works … just. I have no clue whether I am confunded by English in that respect but I would understand *der einfachste Weg* with an infinitive to mean what you want it to mean.

If I thought about it for even a millisecond, I would not use it though. *Die einfachste Art* would be my preferred choice in speaking and *… Methode* in writing.

Other possibilities exist, too, such as *die einfachste Weise* and more.

Comment: It's tricky because in English we use "way" to mean _Art, Weise, Methode, Weg_ usw.

Comment: @147pm I wouldn’t even call it tricky (except for machines which cannot extract context as well as humans can).

Comment: @147pm and that's why they all work.

Comment: _Die einfachste Art und Weise_ is also an alternative, AFAIK. _Art und Weise_ is used as if it were a single word.